# Erro ao desalocar Matriz - double free or corruption C

Tags: c, matriz, memória, alocação, malloc

Olá, estou fazendo um programa para rotacionar uma matriz, que após alocar executa a função de rotação, e então desaloca os dados.
O problema é ao tentar desalocar, está me retornando *double free* or *corruption*

```
cop = malloc(x * sizeof(long int*));
for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
{
    cop[k] = malloc(y * sizeof(long int*));
}

transf(mat,cop,lin,col,theta,variavel);

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    free(cop[i]);
}
free(cop);
```

A função utilizada é essa:

```html
void transf(long int **mat, long int **cop, long int lin, long int col,long int theta, long int var)
{
    long int valor;
    //x*sin(theta*PI/180) + y*cos(theta*PI/180);
    //x*cos(theta*PI/180) - y*sin(theta*PI/180);
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < col; k++)
        {
            long int a = k*cos(theta*PI/180) - i*sin(theta*PI/180);
            long int b = k*sin(theta*PI/180) + i*cos(theta*PI/180);
            a += var;
            cop[b][a] = mat[i][k];
            if (a > 0)
            {
                    cop[b][a-1] = mat[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essa função relaciona a lin/col de uma matriz e rotaciona para b/a de outra (no caso, a matriz cop), x e y é o tamanho da matriz necessario para que a imagem seja rotacionada.
Theta = 90º como exemplo

Comment: acho que isto aqui "cop[k] = malloc(y * sizeof(long int*));" deveria ser assim:  "cop[k] = malloc(y * sizeof(long int));"...não me parece que isso é a causa do erro no free, mesmo assim é algo que está "errado" (no Windows 64 bits, ponteiro é 64 bits mas long int é 32 bits)

Comment: Como está o resto do programa ? Consegue criar um código minimo executavel que apresente o erro que indica ?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, a alocação das linhas da matriz `cop` está possívelmente incorreto. O correto é:

```
for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
{
    cop[k] = malloc(y * sizeof(long int));
}
```

No seu código, você alocou em relação ao tamanho de `sizeof(long int*)`, que depende do tamanho do ponteiro da máquina. Em um sistema operacional (SO) de 32-bits, esse tamanho terá 4 bytes, já em um SO de 64-bits, esse tamanho será 8 bytes. Se não estou enganado, o tamanho do `long int` é 8 bytes em ambos os casos (exceto em arquiteturas bem exóticas).

Uma boa maneira de encontrar a fonte desses problemas é compilar o programa com as flags de debugging (no gcc, `-g`) e utilizar o valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer uma matriz na qual `cop->cop[0]->cop[0][0] == dado`, onde o `dado` é um `long int`, teríamos para o primeiro elemento:

```
long int** cop;
cop = (long int**) malloc(x * (long int*));
cop[0] = (long int*) malloc(y * (long int));
cop[0][0] = dado;
```

Se você quer uma matriz na qual `*cop->cop[0]->cop[0][0] == matriz_original[0][0]`, onde `matriz_original` armazena os dados **diretamente** e `matriz_original[0][0]` é um `long int`, teríamos para o primeiro elemento:

```
long int*** cop;
cop = (long int***) malloc(x * (long int**));
cop[0] = (long int**) malloc(y * (long int*));
cop[0][0] = &matriz_original[0][0]; //matriz_b armazena os dados diretamente, não ponteiros
```

Imagino que a segunda opção faria sentido se cada elemento da matriz original fosse muito grande, então se rotacionaria uma matriz de ponteiros que apontam para a matriz original. No entanto, no caso está subentendido que o tipo de cada unidade de dados é apenas um `long int` e não um ponteiro para uma outra estrutura maior. Talvez você esteja querendo fazer o descrito na primeira opção.

Answer (score 1):

Eu escrevi um pequeno programa para simular a matriz que você está querendo fazer... 
Ao ler e escrever na matriz não tive erros. Também consegui executar o comando free sem problemas.
Dê uma olhada no código que escrevi, execute em sua máquia e talvez você consiga achar o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    long int **cop = (long int **) malloc (x * sizeof(long int *));

    printf("Alocando... \n");
    for (int k = 0; k < x; ++k) {
        cop[k] = (long int*) malloc (x * sizeof(long int));
    }

    printf("Atribuindo... \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j) {
            cop[i][j] = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Imprimindo...\n\n");
    for (int l = 0; l < x; ++l) {
        for (int k = 0; k < x; ++k) {
            printf("k[%d][%d]: %d\n", l, k, cop[l][k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int k = 0; k < x; ++k) {
        free(cop[k]);
    }
    free(cop);

    return 0;
}
```